# Extract and concatenate 3rd dimension of Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

**Background**

From a video of [computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWEXCYQKyDc), I got the idea of playing with [Least Significant Bit Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit).
Now, I am trying to extract and concatenate all RGB values **in bit format** of an Image using Numpy. Eventually, I need only every 7th and 8th bit of the array.

**Setup**

I load the image with `Pillow` and extract the bits in the following way:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('test.png')
arr = np.array(img)
bits = np.unpackbits(arr, axis=2)
```

**Problem**

The `bits` array has now a shape of e.g. (1600, 1200, 24) for a 1600x1200 pixel image. What I need now is

1. to extract the 24 bits for every pixel
2. concatenate all the blocks of 24 bits into a single 1d array.
3. extract only the 7th, 8th, 15th, 16th, 23rd, and 24th bit, so only the last 2 bits of every color component.

**Approach so far**

I tried to [split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split) the 3d array along the 2nd axis into 3 groups. I can then iterate over the 1200 lists of 3 lists each and extract the last 2 bits, like this:

```
sp = np.split(bits, 3, axis=2)
for i in range(0, 1200):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        print(sp[j][0][i][-2:])
```

**Question**

Although my approach above works, I have the feeling that there must be a more performant solution to this using only `Numpy Magic®`. Do you know a better way?

Comment: Try `bits.reshape(1600, 1200, 3, 8)[:,:,:,-2:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to convert the pixels to binary or extract any specific bits with explicit methods, because then you'll have to stitch it all up again. You can directly do what you want with [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), because "binary" and decimal are two representations of the same number. A combination of `AND`s and `SHIFT`s will allow you to zero-out any part of an integer, or isolate a specific range of bits

For example,

```
>> (107 >> 3) & 7
5
```

Because

```
Decimal: 107      >> 3 = 13       & 7        = 5
Binary : 01101011 >> 3 = 00001101 & 00000111 = 00000101
           |-|                |-| 
         we want
         these 3
```

Now, let's say your message is the world 'hello'. You can conveniently chop up each byte in four parts like this.

```
secret = b'hello'
bits = []
for byte in secret:
    for i in range(6, -1, -2):
        bits.append((byte >> i) & 3)
bits = np.array(bits)
```

Since each `bits` elements contains two bits, the values can range between 0 and 3. If you think of the letter 'h' in binary, which is '01|10|10|00', you can see how the first few values of `bits` are 1, 2, 2, 0, etc.

To take advantage of vectorised operations in numpy, we should flatten our image array, which I assume has a shape of (height, width, 3).

```
np.random.seed(0)
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1600, 1200, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
shape = img.shape
# this specific type of flattening puts the pixels in your desired order, i.e.,
# pixel (0, 0) red-green-blue, pixel (0, 1) red-green-blue, etc
flat_img = img.reshape(-1).copy()
```

And now embedding is simply

```
length = len(bits)
flat_img[:length] = (flat_img[:length] & 252) + bits
stego_img = flat_img.reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Great Answer! It not only solved my problem, but taught me about XY questions and bitwise ops as well! For completeness, I will add how to retrieve the text again: Retrieve the bits with `flat_img = flat_img & 3` and sum up every block of 4 with `val = sum([bits[i] << op for i, op in enumerate(range(6, -1, -2))])`. Use `chr(val)` to get the characters of the text again.

Comment: @Peter That's it! Another thing I didn't mention above for the sake of simplicity is when you're using `AND`s and `OR`s, you can express the mask in binary or hexadecimal to make your intentions clearer. 252, 0b11111100 and 0xfc are all the same. For example, assume the ARGB colours of a pixel are all packed in a 32bit number. Once you get the hang of hexadecimal, zeroing out the last bit of each colour plane with `pixel & 0xfefefefe` is self-documenting compared to `pixel & 4278124286`.